# Can Stack Overflow implement shortkey '/' to focus the search box?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, search-box

I found that many websites provide the shortkey '/' as a way to focus the search box like YouTube, Zhihu, etc. However, I found that it doesn't work on Stack Overflow. This feature is written in  front-end JavaScript. Can we add this feature in our website?

```html
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <script>
        var search = document.querySelector('input');
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            // console.log(e.keyCode);
            if (e.keyCode === 191) {
                search.focus();
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

When I press '/' in my keyboard, I can jump to search box and input.

Comment: FYI the `s` key activates the search bar. You can see all keyboard shortcuts by pressing `?`

Comment: Note, to enable the keyboard shortcuts @Phil mentions you can go to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

Comment: Thanks you guys. According to your suggestion, I have set up the shortcut for search box.@Phil @Abdul Aziz Barkat

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Oh yeah, I forgot they have to be enabled

Comment: If enabled in Preferences, they can be discovered by `?` (requires Shift on some keyboards). The zoom level must sufficiently low to see all of them.